# Move/Copy Mail Item To Folder with ItemAdd event generates Error

Tags: vba, outlook

When I call Inbox_ItemAdd to make a **copy** of a Mail Item and then **move** the copy to a different folder, I get an error. The operation completes though.

When I debug the code it steps through without an error. It only errors when I remove the breakpoints. Finally, if I comment out:

```
moveMail.Move DestinationFolder
```

or

```
copied = MoveToFolder(copyMail, FolderName)
```

It creates volumes of copies in the originating folder. Its earliest entry point is from the ItemAdd event, so I'm wondering if

```
Set copyMail = olItem.Copy
```

results in kicking that event off again.

[image: Error]

Here's my **CopyToFolder** and **MoveToFolder** functions:

```
Function MoveToFolder(olItem As Outlook.MailItem, FolderName As String) As Boolean
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim DestinationFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim moveMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set DestinationFolder = objNS.Folders("MyMailBox@mailboxes.com").Folders(FolderName)

    Set moveMail = olItem

    moveMail.Move DestinationFolder

    Set moveMail = Nothing
    Set DestinationFolder = Nothing
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing

End Function

Function CopyToFolder(olItem As Outlook.MailItem, FolderName As String) As Boolean
    Dim copyMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim copied As Boolean

    Set copyMail = olItem.Copy

    copied = MoveToFolder(copyMail, FolderName)
    CopyToFolder = copied

    Set copyMail = Nothing

End Function
```

And I might call the **CopyToFolder** function by:

```
copyResult = CopyToFolder(olItem, "External")
```

Comment: Given this comment in the answer post "It's basically being called from the Inbox_ItemAdd event" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50168055/copy-method-in-itemadd-generates-runtime-error/50225195#50225195

Comment: @niton, Ahhh, it looks like that may very well be the source of the issue. Very cool. I haven't fooled around with this code in a while, but I'll be sure to revisit your answer when I do. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is what MSDN states for the `NewMailEx` event:

> The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the `NameSpace.GetItemFromID` method and process the item. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance. However, depending on the setup on the client computer, after a new message arrives in the Inbox, processes like spam filtering and client rules that move the new message from the Inbox to another folder can occur asynchronously. You should not assume that after these events fire, you will always get a one-item increase in the number of items in the Inbox.

Looks like you have got some rules set up in Outlook. And these rules can be run against the item after the vent handler or asynchronously, i.e. when you try to call the `Move` method. Is it the case?

As a workaround you may consider getting the entry ID and try to get the received item after it's been processed by Outlook. Or just handle the `ItemSend` event instead.

Anyway, you may find the following series of articles helpful:

- [Outlook NewMail event unleashed: the challenge (NewMail, NewMailEx, ItemAdd)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/03/outlook-newmail-event/)
- [Outlook NewMail event: solution options](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/24/outlook-newmail-solution-options/)
- [Outlook NewMail event and Extended MAPI: C# example](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/01/outlook-newmail-extended-mapi/)
- [Outlook NewMail unleashed: writing a working solution (C# example)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/10/outlook-newmail-custom-solution/)

Comment: Thanks Eugene. It's basically being called from the Inbox_ItemAdd event. The rules I have are all in VBA, not Outlook rules just to clarify. I may try the EntryID method, but was just wondering if maybe I'd written the existing code incorrectly somehow. I'll check out the links you've provided. Thanks.

Comment: Okay Eugene. Good to at least get another look from someone. Thank you very much.