# Copy method in ItemAdd generates Runtime Error

Tags: vba, outlook

When I run this code I get the error:

> Run-Time error '-2147221233 (8004010f)':
>   The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found.

Everything is working despite the error.
The error disappears if I change the line

> 'MsgBox "Awesome"

to

> MsgBox "Awesome"

A few tests showed that the error does occur if item.Sendername is used with the copy part. If I do just move the mail it works perfectly.
If I try to use the code separately it works without errors.

```
Private WithEvents snItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set snItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
End Sub

Private Sub snItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
    Dim CopiedItem As MailItem
    Dim ShareInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim MapiNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace

    If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then

        Set MapiNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set ShareInbox = MapiNameSpace.Folders("Support").Folders("Send Mails")

        If item.SenderName = "Support" Then
            Set CopiedItem = item.Copy
            CopiedItem.UnRead = True
            CopiedItem.Move ShareInbox
        End If
    End If

    'MsgBox "Awesome"

ExitRoutine:
    Set ShareInbox = Nothing
    Set CopiedItem = Nothing
    Set MapiNameSpace = Nothing
End Sub
```

There is no error if not copied.
It is ok with the following Code

```
Set MapiNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set ShareInbox = MapiNameSpace.Folders("Support").Folders("Gesendete Elemente")

If item.SenderName = "Support" Then
    item.Move ShareInbox
End If
```

Comment: Since they are the only lines subsequent to MsgBox, I suggest the code is losing track of one of the Objects being set to Nothing. Slowing the processing with a MsgBox, or stepping through the code with F8, is known to sometimes not reproduce errors. This may lead to other problems but as a workaround try deleting a Set = Nothing statement one at a time until there is no error, keeping only the statements that do not cause a problem.

Comment: Removing the Set = nothing does not work. Removing the copy works, but is not really what I want. See Edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying the item adds an item to the Sent Items folder, triggering the ItemAdd code.

Disable the ItemAdd event temporarily.

```
Private Sub snItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
    Dim CopiedItem As MailItem
    Dim ShareInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim MapiNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace

    If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then

        Set MapiNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set ShareInbox = MapiNameSpace.Folders("Support").Folders("Send Mails")

        If item.SenderName = "Support" Then

            ' Turn off event handling
            Set snItems = Nothing

            Set CopiedItem = item.Copy
            CopiedItem.UnRead = True
            CopiedItem.Move ShareInbox

            ' Turn on event handling 
            Set snItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items

        End If
    End If

ExitRoutine:
    Set ShareInbox = Nothing
    Set CopiedItem = Nothing
    Set MapiNameSpace = Nothing
End Sub
```